# Using ってことで to end a sentence

Tags: grammar

> 俺の夢はーー
>
> 遊「公務員かホワイト企業の正社員だ」
>
> 理々「それは夢ではなくて、安定なのではないでしょうか？」
>
> 遊「なら、安定が夢**ってことで**」

How should I understand the phenomenon of using ってことで to end a sentence? How is it different from just だ?

Answer (score 3):

Judging from this question and another question you have posted, I can see you are having some trouble with 「で」. 「で」roughly functions like "with" semantically and syntactically in these expressions. Sometimes "with" alone doesn't quite cut it, but with a few more words, can render this expression in English.

「じゃあ、そういうことで」：With that (said/settled), let's call it a day.

Similarly in your quoted line, 「ってことで」also concludes the conversation or settles that slice of an exchange. More or less something like this:

> [My dream]
>
> 遊: civil servant or full-time employee at a good company
>
> 理々: That's not a dream! It's just a stable plan.
>
> 遊: Okay, my dream is stability then!

Comment: The original sentence literally means "stability is the dream (of mine)", but I feel "stable dream" means the dream itself does not change (e.g. "I've always dreamed of becoming a president since the age 3"). I may be overthinking...

Comment: @naruto Okay this is embarrassing. It was a misreading of the particle on my part... So I took it to be a pun with 「な」... Somehow in the back of my mind I thought that would be a funny way to conclude that exchange.

Comment: Maybe "my dream is stability" is better?